# send a terminal curl post request to a login

Tags: php, forms, curl, post, authentication

I've been trying to send a post request to this login page https://njit2.mrooms.net/auth/saml2/login.php but it doesn't successfully log me in even though the credentials are correct.

here is the full command I'm using in my terminal:
curl --data "j_username=user&j_password=pass&_eventId_proceed=" https://njit2.mrooms.net/auth/saml2/login.php

If you can spot anything that I'm not getting then it'll be much appreciated. Thanks.

edit: with -v flag this is what I get in the beginning of the response:

```
Note: Unnecessary use of -X or --request, POST is already inferred.
*   Trying 34.192.104.23...
* Connected to njit2.mrooms.net (34.192.104.23) port 443 (#0)
* found 148 certificates in /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
* found 597 certificates in /etc/ssl/certs
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* SSL connection using TLS1.2 / ECDHE_RSA_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
*    server certificate verification OK
*    server certificate status verification SKIPPED
*    common name: *.mrooms.net (matched)
*    server certificate expiration date OK
*    server certificate activation date OK
*    certificate public key: RSA
*    certificate version: #3
*    subject: OU=Domain Control Validated,OU=PositiveSSL Wildcard,CN=*.mrooms.net
*    start date: Thu, 30 Nov 2017 00:00:00 GMT
*    expire date: Thu, 17 Jan 2019 23:59:59 GMT
*    issuer: C=GB,ST=Greater Manchester,L=Salford,O=COMODO CA Limited,CN=COMODO RSA Domain Validation Secure Server CA
*    compression: NULL
* ALPN, server did not agree to a protocol
> POST /auth/saml2/login.php HTTP/1.1
> Host: njit2.mrooms.net
> User-Agent: curl/7.47.0
> Accept: */*
> Content-Length: 54
> Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
> 
* upload completely sent off: 54 out of 54 bytes
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
< Date: Mon, 17 Sep 2018 05:54:50 GMT
< Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
< Pragma: no-cache
< Server: Apache
< Set-Cookie: MoodleSession=fe6dc1b41104b83d391d8700d60f9308; path=/
< Set-Cookie: MDL_SSP_SessID=402ef69749885fa74956365b087e5747; path=/; HttpOnly
< Vary: Accept-Encoding
< X-Powered-By: PHP/7.1.15-1+ubuntu14.04.1+deb.sury.org+2
< transfer-encoding: chunked
< Connection: keep-alive
```

Comment: `curl --data "j_username=user&j_password=pass&_eventId_proceed=" -X POST https://njit2.mrooms.net/auth/saml2/login.php` Does that work? Add the `-v` flag so you can get some more information about what is going on during the request/response.

Comment: `_eventId_proceed=` ... No value for this?

Comment: @mulquin I got the same text back but I've included the output of -v above.

Comment: @ChukwuemekaInya I don't know what should go there, it's a hidden field.

Comment: Very strange, you are getting 200 code back which should indicate that everything is OK. Not to mention moodle cookies